# angular.iselement returns false for an element I know exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML document is created with a title element as part of its boilerplate.

In my JS I've got:

```
console.log("angular.isElement('title'): ", angular.isElement('title'));
```

Which pops out 'false' when run. Why does this happen when the element clearly exists? I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious. Ultimately I'm trying to select elements with angular.element() instead of document.getElementById or document.getElementByClass, but it's like the DOM is invisible to Angular. Note that I cannot include jQuery (not my decision). Should I just stick with native JS when trying to access the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because angular.isElement expects a node element or a jQuery wrapped element.
You can change your code to:

```
console.log("angular.isElement('title'): ", angular.isElement(document.querySelector('title')));
```

Compare: [AngularJS documentation on isElement](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isElement?PHPSESSID=cae8e98e7ca559b4605d75c813b358ee)

Comment: Thank you! That works. I could not find a non-jqueried example anywhere.